# Jackson and JsonIgnore to hide secret fields

Tags: java, jackson, dropwizard, morphia

I'm trying to use a combination of dropwizard + morphia + jackson (dropwizard's default), but I can't get `@JsonIgnore` or `@JsonIgnoreProperties` to work. I've tried `@JsonIgnoreProperties` over the class definition for properties I don't want to be exposed (password and salt) to consumers of my API, I've also tried `@JsonIgnore` over the field declarations themselves as well as over every permutation of getter and setter... Kind of at a loss now.

edit: here's the model:

```
@Entity(value = "user", noClassnameStored = true)
@Indexes({
    @Index(fields = {
        @Field(value = "email", type = IndexType.ASC)},
        options = @IndexOptions(unique = true, sparse = true)
    )
})
public class User {
  @Id
  private ObjectId id = new ObjectId();
  @JsonProperty
  private String email;
  @JsonProperty
  private byte[] password;
  @JsonProperty
  private byte[] salt = SecurityUtils.getSalt();
  @Reference
  private Person person = new Person();

  public String getId() {
    return id.toHexString();
  }

  public void setId(ObjectId id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getEmail() {
    return email;
  }

  public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
  }

  @JsonIgnore
  public byte[] getPassword() {
    return password;
  }

  @JsonIgnore
  public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = SecurityUtils.hashPassword(password.toCharArray(), this.getSalt());
  }

  @JsonIgnore
  public byte[] getSalt() {
    return salt;
  }

  @JsonIgnore
  public void setSalt(byte[] salt) {
    this.salt = salt;
  }

  public Person getPerson() {
    return person;
  }

  public void setPerson(Person person) {
    this.person = person;
  }
}
```

In addition to the above I've tried defining the class using `@JsonIgnoreProperties({"password", "salt"} public class User...`, as well as having `@JsonIgnore` only over the getters, setters, etc.

I'm using morphia v1.2.1 to persist. Right now I have a basic DAO that's extending morphia's BasicDAO and mostly just proxying at the moment. Can post snippets of that code if it'll help.

Comment: Maybe you could post your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

password and salt are both labeled `@JsonProperty`, which takes precedence over the ignore on the setter and getter. I think if you remove the JsonPropety annotation (or replace it with JsonIgnore), those fields you want ignored will actually be ignored.

Comment: Yep, you're right. I guess I need to read about `@JsonProperty` more. 

I have a followup question (which I can post to a new question if need be) which would be to allow a PUT for password updates. ie. if I get a request to change a password I'd need to take the raw password from the request, hash it, salt it, and persist it. Would that happen with this current config?

Comment: You should be able to make the object asymmetric by labeling the setter with JsonProperty and the getter with JsonIgnore -- but the field still needs to be labeled JsonIgnore (see http://www.davismol.net/2015/03/21/jackson-using-jsonignore-and-jsonproperty-annotations-to-exclude-a-property-only-from-json-deserialization/)